# LINQ: Where() ignore simple false condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
Expression<Func<SettingItemModel, bool>> func = _ => false;

return GetAllSettingItemModel().Where(func).OrderBy(s => s.OrderParameter);
```

Why if I assign this simple predicate to 'func' instead of `s => s.SettingCategory == -1` (which is always false in my case), I get all the elements as the condition is ignored, instead of getting 0 elements?

I suppose because the SettingItemModel object is not taken into consideration in the predicate, but I am not sure.

Comment: Is `GetAllSettingItemModel()` an IQueryable? What is implementing the IQueryable (e.g. Entity Framework)?

Comment: Yes, it is implemented by Realm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug with your `IQueryable` provider

Theoretically your IQueryable provider can interpret and process that expression however it wants, and it seems doing it incorrectly for a constant `false` values. You will need to raise a bug with your provider.

A workaround might be to bring that expression into memory and do a check on an IEnumerable

```cs
return GetAllSettingItemModel().ToList().Where(func).OrderBy(s => s.OrderParameter);
```

Or if the expression can be evaluated locally do it before executing the query

```cs
return func() ? GetAllSettingItemModel().OrderBy(s => s.OrderParameter) :  Enumerable.Empty<SettingItemModel>();
```